Do LLMs “pause to think”?
Sometimes it seems like an LLM takes longer to respond, perhaps if the question is somehow more difficult. But maybe this is an illusion. Is there any reason that a response would take longer? Is response time length a function of anything, such as input length?

It's an interesting question, I don't understand the downvote

Is your question about the initial delay before the answer appear, the time between the first and the last word in the answer, or both?


Do LLMs “pause to think”?

Not for the current mainstream LLMs.
The time the LLM takes to write the first token depends on the input size (and on the LLM and architecture specific). Then the longer the output, the longer it takes the LLM to generate it.
However it's one could devise more complex architectures whose inference time depends on the query complexity (not just length), eg LLM routing systems https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.12031 or LLM calling tools https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.04761

I believe modern (GPT-4-level) models employ "CoT tokens" that are hidden from the user but still generated and passed through autoregressively.

Yes, LLMs like GPT, Mistral, Llama and  etc do "pause to think." When you ask a question, the model takes a brief moment to consider what you've said and how best to respond. This pause is similar to how a person might take a second to think before answering a question. During this time, the model is figuring out the most relevant information and the best way to present it to you. This helps ensure that the response is clear and appropriate for your query
means if we talking about how llm model understand the query
these process I am explaining here.
when you input a prompt, the model goes through several computational steps to generate a response

Tokenization: Breaking down your input into smaller pieces (tokens).
Contextual Understanding: Analyzing the tokens to understand the context and meaning of the input.
Probability Calculation: Using the model's neural network to predict the next words based on learned patterns from the vast amount of data it was trained on.
Response Generation: Construct a coherent response by selecting the most probable words and phrases.

these steps happen very quickly and give the relevant answer
